# Opensource Data Services Solution

Tags: web-services

Am looking for a product (both open source and commercial) which exposes database as Webservices (SOAP/REST). The product should allow CRUD operations across various tables. One of my colleagues suggested a product from Oracle (Oracle Data Services Integration).

Does anyone know of any open source or commercial products which provides this functionality? Open source products preferable.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [OData](http://www.odata.org/)?

SQL Server supports this protocol, as do [many other products](http://www.odata.org/producers).